# How can I do partial mocking on beans

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have the following JUNIT class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:junit-xxx.xml", "classpath:junit-xxxxx.xml" })
public class TestFictionalClass
{

@Autowired   // I changed this to @Mock so the first "when" below works
private MyService mService


@Before
    @Transactional
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

         Mockito.when((mService).myMockedMethod(Mockito.any(String.class)))
        .thenReturn("Hello");

        Mockito.when((mService).myOtherRealMethod(Mockito.any(BigDecimal.class), Mockito.any(BigDecimal.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

}
```

What I am trying to do here is mock one of the methods so it returns value "hello" always but I want the other method in the class to execute normally. The problem  I am getting the following error on the second method

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Cannot call abstract
>   real method on java object! Calling real methods is only possible when
>   mocking non abstract method.

How can I mock the class in question so I override the value one of it's methods return?

Thank you

PS: I am using Mockito and Spring MVC

Comment: I think you need PowerMock for that. https://github.com/powermock/powermock

Comment: Unfortuetly, I am limited to use Mockito

Comment: I am afraid mockito alone is not powerful enough for that purpose. Are you sure, you cannot use powermock as an extension for mockito? Powermock does not replace mockito. I am pretty sure you can do that with powermock ;-)

Comment: I can't use external libraries but maybe it is included. If you can post an example I can try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of @Mock use @Spy annotation. Spying provides the way to mock only specific methods (with "when-then") and leave others working as they are.

More about spying: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).

Comment: I tried it but it says the MyService is an interface and can not be spied on :(

Comment: Try @SpyBean instead or even try to inject the implementation

Comment: SpyBean is SpingBoot, I am using Spring MVC. What do you mean by inject? You mean use the Implementation to declare class instead of interface?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice about Spring MVC. Yes, I meant to spy on the implementation of MyService rather than on the interface.

Comment: I got it to compile but it had the same effect as mock (all variables are empty inside the class). I will accept this answer meanwhile unless I get a better answer